# How to create and use Java Card library packages?

Tags: java, javacard

As you may know, and as it is mentioned in *Java Card Development Kit User Guide*, the key to writing large applications for the Java Card platform is to divide the code into individual package units. The most important limitation on a package is the 64KB limitation on the maximum component size. This is especially true for the 
Method component: if the size of an application’s Method component exceeds 64KB, 
then the Java Card converter will not process the package and will return an error.

So, we need to use Java Card library packages in some special cases. My question is how to create and how to use these Java Card library packages?

**What am I did so far?**

Well, I wrote a really simple Java Class containing a single method named `sayHello()` as below:

```
package libPack;

import javacard.framework.*;

public class mylib {
    public static final byte[] hello = {(byte)'H',(byte)'e',(byte)'l',(byte)'l',(byte)'o'};

    protected mylib() {
    }

    public void sayHello(APDU apdu) {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(hello, (short)0x00, buffer, (short)0x00, (short)hello.length);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0x00, (short)buffer.length);
    }
}
```

As I couldn't find any option in my IDE-s (Netbeans & Eclipse) to create `cap` file of library packages (Those have plugins for creating `cap` from Applet packages only, I guess), I used command line to create my library's cap file as below:

**1.** Generating the `.class` file of above `.java` program:

```
CMD:> javac -g -source 1.2 -target 1.2 -cp "D:\JCDK\java_card_kit-2_2_2\lib\api.jar" "D:\LibSrc\mylib.java"
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.2
1 warning

CMD:>
```

Above command generate a `.class` file that its name is my library class name. I create a folder in the same directory and named it "libPack" (the program's package name) and then I moved this `.class` file into it.

**2.** Converting the created `.class` file to `.cap` file:

```
CMD:> D:\JCDK\java_card_kit-2_2_2\bin\converter.bat -debug -verbose -exportpath D:\JCDK\java_card_kit-2_2_2\api_export_files -classdir D:\LibSRC libPack 0xa0:0x0:0x0:0x0:0x62:0x3:0x1:0xc:0x6:0x1 1.0

Java Card 2.2.2 Class File Converter, Version 1.3
Copyright 2005 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.

parsing D:\LibSRC\libPack\mylib.class
converting libPack.mylib
parsing D:\JCDK\java_card_kit-2_2_2\api_export_files\java\lang\javacard\lang.exp
parsing D:\JCDK\java_card_kit-2_2_2\api_export_files\javacard\framework\javacard\framework.exp
writing D:\LibSRC\libPack\javacard\libPack.exp
writing D:\LibSRC\libPack\javacard\libPack.jca

conversion completed with 0 errors and 0 warnings.

CMD:>
```

Above command, generate *libPack.cap* and *libPack.exp* files in "libPack\javacard" directory.

**Questions:**

1. Am I did the Java Card Library Package generation process in a right way?
2. How can I use this library package in my applets to reduce my applet packages smaller in size?

---

**Update: (Based on dear Vojta's answer)**

To make whole the process IDE-Independent, I create a `.jar` file of my library `.class` file using the following command in the commandline again:

```
CMD:> jar cfv mylib.jar D:\LibSRC\libPack\mylib.class
CMD:>
```

The above command, created "mylib.jar" from the "mylib.class" file in the command line current directory.

After that I added this "mylib.jar" file and its already created `.exp` file (previous step using Converter) to my Applet project in Netbeans IDE, in the same way that I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162385/how-to-add-javacard-packages-to-javacard-applet/35178787#35178787).

Now I want to use the `sayHello()` method of my library in my applet:

[image]

As you see above, I still receive an error. What's that? As far as I know, I can't define static methods in the library packages (right?), so where I can use library methods?

Comment: did you get it working? did the process generate a cap file for the library project. During the installation, did you install the library cap file first? then the applet cap file? Thanks

Comment: @Johnny All the questions have "yes" answer. But be aware that your card must have that library support already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any Java Card package with some public classes and public methods can be used as a library. If you use Eclipse JCOP Tools, you can build your library very easily: the cap file is created automatically in folder:

```
/[workspace]/[project]/bin/[path according to package]/javacard
```

A Java Card library is just any package; even a package with an `Applet` can be used as one. So there is no real difference between building a "common" `cap` file and a "library" `cap` file.

---

Note there is a little difference between objects implementing `Shareable` interface and static methods in your library package. `Shareable` interface can be used to access object instances in context A through the firewall from the context B. However, `static` methods can be accesses from any context - no firewall rules apply. There is a nice overview of [AppletIsolation and Object Sharing here](http://pfa12.free.fr/doc_java/javacard_specifications/specs/jcre/html/JCRESpec06firewall.html). The most important paragraph on `static` methods is 6.1.6:

> Instances of classes—objects—are owned by contexts; classes themselves are not. There is no runtime context check that can be performed when a class static field is accessed. Neither is there a context switch when a static method is invoked.
>
> Public static fields and public static methods are accessible from any
>   context: static methods execute in the same context as their caller.
>
> Objects referenced in static fields are just regular objects. They are
>   owned by whomever created them and standard firewall access rules
>   apply. If it is necessary to share them across multiple contexts, then
>   these objects need to be Shareable Interface Objects (SIOs).
>
> Of course, the conventional Java technology protections are still
>   enforced for static fields and methods. In addition, when applets are
>   installed, the Installer verifies that each attempt to link to an
>   external static field or method is permitted. Installation and
>   specifics about linkage are beyond the scope of this specification.

Shortly speaking: no static objects in your static library = no `Shareable` needed.

---

You sometimes need to use an existing library in your new applet, although you do not have the source code of the library. The library might have been loaded to your card by the vendor or by some third party. You need a `jar` file and an `exp` file of the library to be able to use it in your applet.

You need class files of the library in a common Java `jar` file to build your new class files by the Java compiler. Then you need some extra information for the Java Card Converter to link your code with library classes and their methods. That is what `exp` files are used for. The `exp` file describes the interface and dependencies of all public components in a `cap` file. Eclipse JCOP Tools creates the `exp` file together with the `cap` file in the same folder, as well as the Java Card Converter does. ([See the documentation by Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javacard/documentation/applet-136808.html#expfl))

The `exp` file and the `jar` file is all you need to build your code which uses the library. Just put them both into your project  and make sure the `jar` file is on the build path of your project.

Feel free to ask.

Comment: _A Java Card library is just any package; even a package with an Applet can be used as one._ : Well, I was thought that there is a different between library packages and applet packages and that is that I can use the Applet package public methods only through the `Shareable` interface, while for library packages we don't need this interface anymore. Am I wrong?

Comment: Anyway, does adding this `.jar` file to my applet and using its methods will generate a smaller `cap` file from my applet in comparison with the case that I define and implement `sayHello()` method inside the applet itself?

Comment: @Abraham on the error you receive: it is a common Java error, you forgot to mark your method 'static', so you cannot invoke it in the static way... I will answer your questions when I am at PC, typing on mobile phone is difficult.

Comment: @Abraham See my edit about `Shareable` and static methods. Yes, the generated cap file would be smaller, because in Java Card there is always one cap file for one package. You moved some classes to a different library package - that will make your applet package smaller...

Comment: Dear Vojta, may I invite you to take a look at [this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108150/rpk-algorithm-in-smart-cards) room please?

Comment: @Abraham Hi, Abraham, I have no real-world experience with RPK algorithm, unfortunately. As far as I understand it does not seem to be much simpler than RSA - you have to compute multiplication in a large finite field. I have never met any card supporting it. And I think implementing it in Java Card without coprocessor access would be almost as difficult as implementing RSA, which means it is almost impossible...